# HttpPost parameters BasicNameValuePair in Java

Tags: java, http, http-post, basicnamevaluepair

I have to pass a parameters list to an Http POST call.

The actual JSON expected from the server is:

```
{
 "par1": "val1",
 "par1": "val1",
 "par3": ["val1", "val2", "val3"]
}
```

Here's the Java stub:

```
List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("par1", "val1"));
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("par2", "val2"));
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("par3", "["val1", "val2", "val3"]"));
```

this is how I pass parameters to `HttpPost` object:

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));
```

The endpoint expects an array as the 4° line says and I have no idea on how to pass it as array.

Tried searching on Stackoverflow and found the following solutions:

```
//inside for loop
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(String.format("par[%d]", incremental), "value"+incremental));
```

or

```
//inside for loop
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("par[]", "value"+incremental));
```

or

```
String values = "" +
            "[" +
                "\"val1\"," +
                "\"val2\"," +
                "\"val3\""
            "]";


parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("par3", values ));
```

Actually, I cannot debug the server side so I can't say if they're correct or not. Since now none of them had worked.

How can I make it on java?

Answer (score 0):

The actual JSON from server is

> "par1": "val1",
>
> "par1": "val1",
>
> "par3": ["val1","val2","val3"]

I think the problem is That you are getting

> "par1": "val1"

Twice from the server side.
Change the second to

> par2 : 'val2'